# Warning icon and an empty message in iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, submission

I had a warning icon and an empty message in iTunes Connect when selecting to add a build  to Submit for Review.

[image]

Will my app get rejected because of this warning?

Comment: no this is not warning.....i submitted my...it's apple bug...

Comment: @Maulik Thanks, I fear that my application will be rejected.
So, can I continu submission without any problem?

Comment: ya.. you can submit....same problem display in my itunes...

Comment: if any problem then apple mail to you...

Comment: I have the same problem, but additionally all builds are stuck in processing. Did you faced that issue before posting the question?

Comment: @DevAndArtist, Yes, you should waiting until apple complete processing your build.
Good Luck :)

Comment: Came across this today. Then later it just suddenly disappear.

Comment: yes...I confirm that @Teffi... same behaviour happened...

Comment: I had the same thing, it didn't affect my app submission at all.

Answer (score 1):

It was an Apple bug before iTunesConnect site been updated. Sometimes the description box states that you have beta xCode application (if you really don't have it - just ignore the warning).
It will disappear eventually. Sometimes it takes up to **3 days** to process the build - but in the end it'll go away for sure.