# iTunesconnect build has warning

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

The app was uploaded to itunes connect but when adding and selecting a build, the build has a warning sign. However, tapping on the warning sign doesn't show any info. Any idea what could be the cause for this issue? Re uploading will not change anything.

[image]

Comment: What is your IPA size ?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32828312/warning-icon-and-an-empty-message-in-itunes-connect

Comment: iTunesConnect is really terrible